# How can I avoid repeating the same annotation arguments everywhere?

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I'm using an annotation from a library that requires a list of arguments, and there are a lot of classes throughout my project that use this annotation with those exact same arguments.

```kotlin
@AnnotationFromDependency(values = [long, list, of, variables, that, might, change])
class Foo {
    fun bar() {
        println("dostuff")
    }
}
```

How can I avoid copying the same arguments for `@AnnotationDependency` to every class that uses it? Defining the arguments list in a variable does not work because it is not a compile-time constant.

```kotlin
val myValues = arrayOf("long", "list", "of", "values", "that", "might", "change")

@AnnotationFromDependency(values = myValues) // error: An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant
class Foo {
    fun bar() {
        println("dostuff")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alex.T only primitives and Strings are allowed as constants, not arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a custom annotation and annotate it with the third-party one:

```kotlin
@AnnotationFromDependency(values = ["long", "list", "of", "variables", "that", "might", "change"])
annotation class MyAnnotation()
```

**Note:** *Meta-annotations are annotations applied to other annotations.*

Next, use your annotation instead of the third party one where needed:

```kotlin
@MyAnnotation
class Foo()
```

If you ever need to modify the list of values you will only need to do it in one place.

Comment: Is there official documentation for this behavior? I had no idea you could do this!

Comment: This is how annotations were designed in Java and nothing stops you from taking advantage of it in Kotlin.